# If I fits on the Board, I sits on the Board

Tags: present-tense, third-person-singular

I recently saw text on that [picture](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/80sh4c/university_therapy_cat_running_for_board_of/), over the reddit. It says "If I fits on the Board, I sits on the Board". Since that looks like official and formal signboard, I am curious as to why authors used "fits" and "sits" instead of "fit" and "sit". Are there any suggestions ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very *folksy* and informal way of talking, as in

> If I sees it, I eats it.

usually associated with a form of northern *rural* speak (Maine, Minnesota) which has been adopted by certain feline dialects.

You also need to consider this is in Minnesota (read: *long cold winters leading to cabin fever*) at a famous liberal arts college (read: *creative types*) and they are trying to give the cat a certain *personality*.

Also, notice the *punning* in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "meme" based on videos of cats sitting in boxes that seem to small with the quote "If I fits I sits". This is incorrect language and is intentionally incorrect to sound "cute", perhaps mimicking the way the cat would talk if it could.